# Google analytics in iframe content (different domain)

Tags: iframe, google-analytics

I have been reading some google documentation on tracking via google analytics, but still hasn't have a clear understanding of what's happening, I will put this in plain english so that my query can help others as well.

Basically I have 2 sites: siteA.com (parent), and siteB.com (child)

I have created a widget on siteB.com, i.e. siteB.com/widget. Let's say in this case I embed siteB.com/widget on siteA.com (home page)

```
<iframe src="http://siteB.com/widget"></iframe>
```

And on siteB.com, I have the relevant google analytics installed. So my question is:

Will siteB.com google analytics be able to register siteA traffic? (one traffic to siteA.com equals to siteB.com/widget.)

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short Answer : No, It is not as simple

For cross browser tracking:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite?csw=1#trackingIFrames

> In a site where the transfer between domains is done by opening a new
>   window or by including     content in an iFrame, you will need to to
>   use the _getLinkerUrl() method to transfer visitor and campaign
>   cookies from one domain to another. For example, suppose you include a
>   form in an iFrame that is hosted on www.my-example-iframecontent.com.
>   In order to transfer visitor information from the parent page that
>   hosts the iFrame on www.example-parent.com, you would use JavaScript
>   to load the iFrame and pass in the cookie information using the
>   _getLinkerURL() method.

There are different ways to setup and it all depends on your configuration. Therefore, I suggest that you setup some test profile and experiment with your settings.

Comment: Hi, siteA.com (parent) and siteB.com (child) is different domains. Are you saying that the GA code on siteB.com/widget will not be able to register any traffic from siteA.com?

Comment: Hi, one more simple questions, with the simple setup above (GA on siteB), will it be able to register 1 page view if siteA loads?

Comment: Yes, I guess the downfall I see here is that you will have to use javascript to load the iframe and pass the cookie info as mentioned in the article

Comment: hi, thanks for the helpful answer, it does help, we have tested this on our site and in short, by adding analytics on siteB.com/widget, it register page view when siteA.com(containing the siteB.com/widget) is loaded. But like you say, to pass the complete traffic info from siteA.com to siteB.com, _getLinkerURL() method should be used.